# Error 500 trying to create Vertex using Rest API

Tags: orientdb

I'm trying to create a Vertex using the Rest API. I've been able to successfully use the Rest API to create a database, and to create classes (but without extending the "V" object).
However, when I try to create a Vertex using the "command" POST, I always get an error 500.

From Fiddler, here is my POST data:

```
POST http://dbserver:2480/command/G4JTest-8587569988225882445/sql HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Authorization: Basic cm9vdDpkYktpbmc=
Host: dbserver:2480
Content-Length: 105
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"command": "create class :classname extends V", "parameters": { "classname": "TestCreateVertexVertex"} }
```

Here's my response:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Sun Oct 11 17:01:44 PDT 2015
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: OrientDB Server v.2.1.2 (build UNKNOWN@r; 2015-09-09 21:41:27+0000)
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 349

{
  "errors": [{
      "code": 500,
      "reason": 500,
      "content": "com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandExecutorNotFoundException: Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.{\"command\": \"create class :classname extends V\", \"parameters\": { \"classname\": \"TestCreateVertexVertex\"} }"
      }
  ]
}
```

Can someone please explain what I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

This was answered in another forum. The JSON post capability is only available in version 2.2. Since I am using 2.1.x, the error is not un-expected ...

Since 2.2 is Alpha, I'll be using the older REST interface for commands.

Or RTFM (more carefully ...)